# Insert static data along with data loading wizard utility in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I am new with Oracle APEX and trying to explore all options in APEX (5.1). My query is related to Data loading wizard in Oracle APEX. I created one table which has three columns, and I set up that table as Data Load Definitions.

This is the process that I expect through the data loading wizard:

1. In the first page of Data load Source, I created one radio page item and by selecting that, it should be assigned to the first column in the table.
2. I will upload a CSV file with two columns which will be assigned to the second and third columns.

So, whatever records are there in the CSV file, by selecting page item that static strings need to be inserted along with file data.

I Googled the same thing but I didn't find any proper solution for this requirement. If you can help me then it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred approach for this sort of thing is to use a staging table as the target of the Data Load wizard; then add a process at the end that copies the rows from the staging table to the final table, setting the static column(s) at the same time; then delete the rows from the staging table.

Note: add a column `SESSION_ID` to the table with a trigger that sets it to `v('SESSION')` so that the process will only pick up rows for the current user session.